# Installing Ubuntu touch on samsung galaxy tab 2 p3100

Tags: ubuntu-touch, samsung, tablet

I need some one guidance to install **ubuntu touch** on my **samsung galaxy tab 2 p3100** and i also wanna know what all **app's supports** it like whats's app, wechat, and wordpress ect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an old build (Apr-2013), but you may still need to wait a few more weeks.

The number of devices support for daily builds is in the process of being extended.

Changes to **phablet-flash** will shortly support additional devices and sources, rather than some complicated install procedure more suited to ***XDA-developers*** (no slight intended).

http://sergiusens.github.io/posts/updates-to-phablet-flash.html

**UPDATE**

Also look at: [Ubuntu Touch Porting: next steps](https://daniel.holba.ch/blog/tag/porting/)

---

The 'current status' for **Galaxy Tab 2 7.0** (GT-P3100/P3110/P3113) can be found at:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/p3100 (3G + WiFi)

and

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/p3110 (WiFi only)