# Installing the Touch Preview on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, samsung, tablet

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (7.0). I have never liked the Android OS or the tablet in general, and wanted to try out Ubuntu Touch. I have done multiple searches on the internet to try to figure out the process of rooting the tablet and installing the new OS (I am a developer in general and am good with an Ubuntu terminal, but have absolutely no experience with the bowels of Android), but haven't found anything useful. I was looking for some (simple) instructions on installing Touch on the Galaxy Tab 2, using either a Windows PC or an Ubuntu laptop (whichever works). I have found a few other posts, but many are old and refer to multiple different, fractured tutorials.

Can anyone give me some instructions on installing touch on my tablet?

**NOTE:** Before anyone marks this as a duplicate, I have looked through all of the other questions about this on these and other forums. So far, I have not found any that answer my question.

Comment: What are you asking, not covered by: http://askubuntu.com/questions/330897/installing-ubuntu-touch-on-samsung-galaxy-tab-2-p3100 ?

Comment: I don't know enough about Android tablets or Ubuntu Touch to find any instructions in that post. If you can point me to the information that I am looking for in that post, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: *You are quite correct.* Other than for **Nexus 7** (7" tablet), **Nexus 10** (10" tablet) and **Nexus 4** (smartphone) you are going have difficulty. Alternatively, wait for the **phablet-flash** utility to support additional 'community' build, which should include the Galaxy Tab 2 series.

Comment: Is this something that will show up soon or could it be a while? Is supporting other devices a priority for them?

Comment: The most recent status (that sounded promising) is: https://daniel.holba.ch/blog/2013/08/join-our-ubuntu-touch-porting-clinic-today/ Also check out Mailing List Archive: https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/maillist.html

Comment: It whether it is a GT-p3100, GT-p3110, or a GT-p3113. Try looking at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/
and see if your model is there

Comment: Since I asked this question, I have been attempting to install touch. I went through all of the steps listed on the page for my tablet maintained by a 3rd-party maintainer, but when my tablet boots, it's just a blank screen. I noticed that the 3rd-party page hasn't been updated in a long time. It there official support for the p3113 now? Or have they just abandoned it? Is there any way that I can get someone to work on it (I don't know enough to do it myself)? I have many unanswered questions, and will probably post a new question soon to see if anyone can shed some light on the situation.